# Is there a way to modify cookies in a redirected request in Manifest V3?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am trying to implement a "cookie sandbox" in a Chrome extension, where different tabs of the same website won't affect each other's cookies.

With the `webRequestBlocking` API this would have been mostly straightforward, but with its deprecation I've had to rely on a blend of listening for cookie changes via the `cookies` API and modifying outgoing request headers through the `declarativeNetRequest` API.

This is racy, because I need the following to occur in this exact order:

1. Tab X receives a response with a `Set-Cookie` header. Chrome modifies the cookie accordingly.
2. Through `chrome.cookies.onChanged`, I am notified of this cookie's change.
3. I use `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules` and give it a rule to manually set the `cookie` header to the new cookie in requests originating from tab X.
4. Tab X sends a new request, and the `declarativeNetRequest` rules set the hardcoded cookie from step 3 (meaning that other tabs' network requests can't affect Tab X's outgoing cookies).

This exact order usually holds up well - though it seems to me to have a dangerous dependency on Chrome internals - but there is a flow wherein it breaks down:

1. Tab X receives a response with a `Set-Cookie` header and an HTTP Status Code of 302 - which causes a redirect.
2. Chrome immediately sends a new request to the redirected location, using existing `declarativeNetRequest` rules, which are not updated with the new cookie value.
3. I get notified about the cookie change from step 1, and only now can I update the rules.

In other words, the problem is that when receiving a 302 status code, Chrome immediately sends out a redirected request without giving a chance for asynchronous code to run between the requests.

---

Is there a way to implement this functionality now that `webRequestBlocking` is deprecated?

Comment: Does the rule with the cookie value apply to all requests including the redirected one? If not, why? If it does, there may be a mistake in the code or this is a bug in Chrome or just an incorrect implementation in the API.

Comment: Yes, it applies to all requests in the tab (including the redirected one) - but the problem is when you have a response with a 302 status code that also defines a new cookie. The initial response (with the 302) will have a new cookie in the `Set-Cookie` header, but any changes you make with `declarativeNetRequest` will not apply to the redirected request - meaning that this new cookie won't be sent in the redirected request.

Comment: Well, in that case, my point was that it's a bug.

Comment: A bug in Chrome? To be fair to it, I can understand Chrome's behavior - when it receives the 302 response, it has no reason *not* to immediately send the redirected request. Is there some guarantee of running asynchronous code between the initial 302 response and the redirected request?

Comment: DNR purpose is to change the requests, so not applying the rule to a request is definitely a bug, assuming you do have a matching rule. There are no guarantees for timing when not using webRequestBlocking or its analog in chrome.debugger.

Comment: DNR is "working" - it is applying the old-cookie rule - but because of timing I can't seem to change the rule to support the new cookie between the 302 and the redirected request. If there are no timing guarantees, is it correct to infer that my desired functionality is impossible in V3? Will extensions like SessionBox be impossible when `webRequestBlocking` is removed?

Comment: The only possible workaround I see is chrome.debugger API, but it shows a warning when used. Or you can tell the users to install your extension via ExtensionInstallForcelist which allows webRequestBlocking. You can also suggest your use case in https://crbug.com so they consider implementing it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help - if you want to move your comments over to an answer I'll accept it. Incidentally, I've probably been helped over a dozen times while developing the extension by your answers on Stackoverflow - you're an Internet asset.